# Visual Basic with login form

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using SQL Server. I have a table with three columns `(id, username, password)`.

I have a login form. I would kindly request some help with this code. It is a loop which checks the first column of my database, `id`, against the text in the login textbox and works.

```
For f As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1         
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(f).Cells(0).Value) = TextBox1.Text Then
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
    End If
Next
```

But if I enter both the column indices, `1` and `2` (that is `username` and `password`) then it doesn't work.  So if I put:

```
For f As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1         
    If (DataGridView1.Rows(f).Cells(1).Value) = TextBox1.Text and
        (DataGridView1.Rows(f).Cells(2).Value) = TextBox1.Text Then
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
    End If
Next
```

then it doesn't work.

I would kindly ask if someone can help me with this.

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: I give up: what's the DataGridView for?

Comment: You are using MSSQL and vb.net. Why not use SQL statement to check username and password? I can see you are initially displaying all username/password table data through a DataGridView and comparing your TextBox value to DataGridView values.

Comment: It's doubtful that *both* columns will match the value of `TextBox1.Text` unless someone uses a really *dumb* password.

Comment: You said that the DataGridView 1st Column is Username and 2nd is the password ? based on your logic TextBox1.Text is Equal to Username and Also Password ? hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

As @WilliamPrice correctly noted, you are attempting to match both the username and password against a single textbox.  I'm sure this is not what you intended.